# Cannot connect to remote server with x2goclient, getting connection failed - found existing ssh-agent

Tags: linux, x2go

I used to use x2go for tunneling my entire remote desktop over SSH, but recently trying it yielded no success.

This is the error:

```
Connection failed. * keychain 2.8.4 ~ http://www.funtoo.org * Found existing ssh-agent: 7185 * Known ssh key: /home/w/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

I am running keychain to manage my ssh keys, but I don't see that being an issue.  I also have google authenticator setup (2-factor auth), but even disabled that in PAM to confirm that was not the culprit.

I don't see any errors in the logs and can see that it does take the public key, but beyond that, I haven't a clue what else could be going on.

Comment: Do all expected keys show up in your list of cached keys with `ssh-add -l` ... and when disabling GA, did you also change the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes` to `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`

Comment: #1. yes, #2 yes - previously set.  I also tried disabling compression, no change.  Lastly, I was thinking I changed the ciphers and host key algorithms a while back without having tested x2go, let me try finding a wider set of algorithms to see if that may be it.  Also, is it related to: X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. By adding `--quiet` when starting keychain in .profile, I could again use the x2go client to access the server.

`eval keychain --quiet --eval --agents ssh....`

Comment: I am unable to validate this presently as I no longer have x2go setup on my machines.